# Add an onclick handler for every item in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an `onclick` event for every button that has a child in my program. Initially when I was using `getElementsByClassName` I was unaware of the fact that it returns an array (obvious now in hindsight) unlike `getElementById` that only returns one item. So I edited my code to *iterate* over all button elements, but still to no avail:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run );
function run(){
  allLIElements = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
  for (i=0; i < allLIElements.length; i++){
    var li = allLIElements[i];
    if ( li.firstElementChild != null ){
      li.classList.add('myBtn');
      // tests whether or not the element has been given the proper class
      document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = li.classList;
    }
  };

  }

//**Returns an HTMLcollection not a nodeList**

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

for (i=0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};
}
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a link to show what's happening, so right now when I click on "customer 6" for example I want a modal to appear: https://jsfiddle.net/0k617jsq/

Basically nothing is happening when I click on the button, the modal isn't activating.

Comment: are there any errors in your browser **developer** tools console

Comment: Look into addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @RobG It used to be list of LIs but I changed it, I don't think that's the problem as the modal is still inactive

Comment: @JaromandaX There's no errors

Comment: @Amon, the condition is always false as `li.firstElementChild` is always `null`.

Comment: @jrook - how can you tell if you can't see the HTML?

Comment: Alert the length of btn and see what you get. Like so: 
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn"); alert (btn.length);

Comment: @JaromandaX: I can't so I assumed we start with plain buttons. The question needs the html code too.

Comment: @W.Scott The length is 0. I think the reason is the event is fired after the body of script is executed so the event listener does not have any effects. But I may be wrong.

Comment: The [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) says `The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed,`. This means the body of the script has finished executing before the `run` function is fired by the event listener

Comment: @jrook that seems correct. An Alert message would confirm. I misses that } in the middle of the code.

Comment: Just added the html

Comment: @Amon, to prove that firing of `run` occurs too late, just put a `console.log("DOMContent loaded")` inside the `run` function and put a `console.log("program started")` inside the main script. You will see that the main body is always executed before the `run` function so `run` does not get any chance to do anything.

Comment: Okay looks like you're right, in the console the "program started" message appears first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) state that:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

This means before the `run` functions is executed, the javascript engine tries to execute this line:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
```

And since no button *probably* has the class `myBtn` at this point, no handlers will be assigned to any button. One solution (among many) would be to put the var assignment and the for loop that assigns the onclick events inside the `run` function.

Comment: Where in the run function should I place it? I posted the code here with your fix, doesn't work still https://jsfiddle.net/0k617jsq/

Comment: Nvm I just got it to work finally! Thank you so much really

Comment: Ok. You can take a look at this too: https://jsfiddle.net/0k617jsq/5/ . The modal event fires correctly in this fiddle.

Comment: Okay thanks, what's the benefit of this method? I'll use it

Comment: @Amon: You had it correct. There were just a few syntax errors and `}`s in wrong places. [This] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) might also be helpful as it discusses javascript event model in some detail.

Comment: Also looks like the issue now is that the modal is appearing regardless if the button is a parent or not

Comment: @Amon, you can add a check for that before assigning the click event listener too.

Comment: Like a simple boolean statement? Ill try it

Comment: nvm I got it, forgot I changed back "button" to "LI" when collecting the classes when I was playing around with it

Answer (score 1):

You should post a working example that shows the issue, otherwise we're left to guess the missing parts. Below is what can be deduced from your code.

It more or less works, so if you were to show the HTML, likely a helpful answer will ensue. You need to hide the modal on load.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run );
function run(){
  allLIElements = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
  for (i=0; i < allLIElements.length; i++){
    var li = allLIElements[i];
    if ( li.firstElementChild != null ){
      li.classList.add('myBtn');
      // tests whether or not the element has been given the proper class
      document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = li.classList;
    }
  };

  }

//**Returns an HTMLcollection not a nodeList**

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// hide modal initially
modal.style.display = "none";

for (i=0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = ""; // Use empty string, not 'block'
};
}
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myModal {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">A button <span>with an element child</span></button>
<div>Check: <span id="check"></span></div>
<div id="myModal">the modal<br>
<span class="close">close</span></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0k617jsq/ When I click on "customer 6" I want a modal to appear for example. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I just got it to work, I placed the var declarations and events in the run() function